# how would i convert shared_ptr<ID3D11Buffer> to ID3D11Buffer**

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, direct3d

There is this function that requires a `**ID3D11Buffer` *(where `vertexBuffer.get()` currently is*). I have the following code:

```
shared_ptr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexBuffer;
this->graphicContext->GetDevice()->CreateBuffer( &bd, &srd, vertexBuffer.get() );
```

> argument of type "ID3D11Buffer *" is incompatible with parameter of type "ID3D11Buffer **"

How would i get a pointer to a pointer? `vertexBuffer.get()` just returns a pointer

Comment: Is there anything i can add to clarify my question?

Comment: An explanation of *why* the function requires a `**ID3D11Buffer` would help. For example, does it create one if one doesn't exist? Or does it always replace the buffer with a new one? Or what?

Comment: Usually when you see something like that, the function is going to create and return the buffer for you buy updating the given pointer. That hints there's likely a DeleteBuffer out there to perform clean-up. If that's the case, you do not want to automate the destruction logic with a stock smart pointer. At the very least you'll want to provide a deleter to handle the specialized destruction.

Comment: Looks like `ID3D11Buffer` is a COM interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `CCOMPtr` or something instead of `shared_ptr`? I'm sure you can get the latter to do what you want, but when there are purpose built alternatives, why bother? If you must use `shared_ptr`, I'd go with beerboy's answer and use a raw pointer to begin with, create the buffer, and transfer ownership to the `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not clear what the semantics of `CreateBuffer` is or why you would be passing it a buffer that already exists.

```
ID3D11Buffer* buf = vertexBuffer.get();
this->graphicContext->GetDevice()->CreateBuffer( &bd, &srd, &buf);
if (buf != vertexBuffer.get())
    vertexBuffer = new shared_ptr<ID3D11Buffer> (buf);
```

This requires `ID3D11Buffer` to have a constructor that takes ownership of an `ID3D11Buffer *`. Without that, this will only work if the function never creates a buffer and only takes an `ID3D11Buffer **` so it can create one if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: @beerboy That's correct if `ID3D11Buffer` doesn't have a proper destructor. But if that's so, I'd prefer wrapping it in an RAII class with a proper destructor rather than constructing the `shared_ptr` differently.

Comment: For COM objects like ``ID3D11Buffer``, don't use ``std::shared_ptr``. Use ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr``.

Answer (score 3):

You have to acquire the buffer into a raw pointer:

```
ID3D11Buffer* vbptr;
HRESULT hr = this->graphicContext->GetDevice()->CreateBuffer( &bd, &srd, &vbptr);
IF(FAILED(hr))
{
    // an error occurred...
}
```

Then assign it correctly to a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that calls `Release`:

```
std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexBuffer(vbptr, &ID3D11Buffer::Release);
```